# “Bei vielen Menschen ist es bereits eine Unverschämtheit, wenn sie Ich sagen.”

Tags: translation, german-to-english, difference

This is a quote from Theodor W. Adorno’s *Minima Moralia*.

One can find it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131114172541/http://www.offene-uni.de/archiv/textz/textz_phil/minima_moral.pdf) in German:

> Bei vielen Menschen ist es bereits eine Unverschämtheit, wenn sie Ich sagen.

Or [here](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/adorno/1951/mm/ch01.htm) in English:

> With many people, it’s already an exercise in shamelessness, when they say I.

Googling results mostly in this:

> In many people it is already an impertinence to say ‘I’.

So what is the nuance of *Unverschämtheit*? *Exercise in shamelessness* and *impertinence* seem to be quite different. In the end of the day, it might be a question for [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), but I’m not sure. There is not a lot of context but I presume one has to understand some Adorno-stuff.

Comment: _impertinence_ is the translation of _Unverschämtheit_ and _shamelessness_ is its cognate. I wouldn’t say it’s a false friend, though, because it’s still very close in meaning, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

As a German native, I would translate it with *effrontery*:

> With many people, it’s already an effrontery, when they say ‘I’.

I think that *impertinence* might fit better when compared with *shamelessness*. When hearing *unverschämt* in German, it’s a nuance more emotional (expressing a rage) than other words like e.g. *schamlos*, especially in spoken language.
Be aware that the original sentence is quite weird for a German and would really make him retain a short while as the chaining of *sie* and *ich* is a bit artificial.

Comment: I can’t agree with the sentence struture being awkward in any way, because it is the *only* grammatical way to structure the subordinate clause but otherwise nice answer and +1.

Comment: I like effrontery. I feel like the etymological *-front-* emphasises the emotional (rage) expression. But I agree with Jan: Why do you reckon that it is a "quite weird" sentence?